# Error Language string failed to load: connect_host

Tags: php, phpmailer, hosting

Es la primera vez que me encuentro en esta situación ya que tampoco he tocado mucho de servidores y la empresa me ha pedido si puedo solucionar el problema.

El problema viene siendo que tienen varias webs idénticas  pero con algún que otro texto cambiado, en el formulario de contacto, hay una web que funciona adecuadamente y envía un mail a la empresa y un mail al usuario de confirmación pero hay otras de estas páginas que siguen enviando el mail al usuario pero no lo envían a la empresa y la web arroja el error

> Language string failed to load: connect_host

He buscado que podía ser este error y me he topado con muchos comentarios acerca de que es de phpmailer, con algún problema con el idioma, he comprobado los archivos y son exactamente iguales en la web que va mal y en la web que va bien, de hecho me han dicho que hasta hace unos días funcionaba correctamente y dudo que hayan cambiado el código de la web.

Por lo tanto he de suponer que el problema está en el hosting, he probado a enviar un mail al correo de la empresa que debería recibir este formulario y lo recibe correctamente. En cambio en la web sigue arrojando este error.

He probado a colocar los ficheros de lenguaje de la web que funciona bien la web que no por si acaso. Pero sigo en las mismas.

He creado un nuevo email por si había algún error con el anterior pero el error persiste por lo tanto tampoco parece que sea válido con probar con un nuevo mail.

También he leido algo acerca de que puede ser un error de smtp pero desconozco como arreglarlo si fuera el caso. Estoy usando Hostinger.

Estoy completamente perdida, ya que se me están agotando las ideas y por mi falta de conocimiento no he logrado arreglarlo.

A alguien más le ha pasado? porque fue el error? Gracias!

Edit:

En los errores de log aparece este fallo AH01276: Cannot serve directory /home/directorio/public_html/php/: No matching DirectoryIndex (index.php,index.php7,index.php5,index.perl,index.pl,index.plx,index.ppl,index.cgi,index.jsp,index.jp,index.phtml,index.shtml,index.xhtml,index.html,index.htm,index.js) found, and server-generated directory index forbidden by Options directive

pero realmente no se si tiene algo que ver con el mensaje de error de mi web el de lenguaje algo que me chirria de este error es que aparece la carpeta php en la ruta del error pero no se si es porque hicieron alguna prueba directamente con mi fichero de gracias.php que se encuentra ahí dentro.

El fichero gracias.php es el que se recibe después de llenar el formulario y es el que debería de verse, pero en cambio solo sale el mensaje de error.

este sería mi fichero .htcacces

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.web.es/$1 [R,L]

#Dominio1 sin www a www.web.es
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^web\.es [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.web.es/$1 [L,R=301]

errorDocument 404 /error404.php

redirect 301 /cookies/ http://www.web.es/politica-cookies/
```

y un montón de redirects más

Comment: Hola. Necesitamos ver el bloque de código donde se dispara el error. Por lo general los mensajes de error te dicen en qué archivo y línea ocurre. Si no, revisa el log de errores. Pulsa en [edit] para completar la pregunta. Agrega también el texto del mensaje de error.

Comment: Hola @A.Cedano, no he puesto el código porque el código anteriormente funcionaba bien, y de un dia a otro empezo a salir el error solo en algunas webs, todas tienen el mismo codigo, por lo tanto debe de ser algo del servidor, no creo que sea del código, pero desconozco que pueda ser.

Comment: El error que aparece en la web al enviar el formulario es Language string failed to load: connect_host

Comment: Busca en el log de errores de ese servidor o carpeta donde está fallando, sin datos más específicos no podremos aventurarnos a adivinar qué es lo que está fallando.

Comment: @A.Cedano este es el unico error que parece aparecer  AH01276: Cannot serve directory /home/directorio/public_html/php/: No matching DirectoryIndex (index.php,index.php7,index.php5,index.perl,index.pl,index.plx,index.ppl,index.cgi,index.jsp,index.jp,index.phtml,index.shtml,index.xhtml,index.html,index.htm,index.js) found, and server-generated directory index forbidden by Options directive    podría estar relacionado?

Comment: ¿Podrías agregar el contenido del archivo `httpd.conf` a la pregunta pulsando en [edit]? Considera cambiar posible información sensible o personal como nombre del sitio web u otros.

Comment: @A.Cedano mi servidor diría que no me da acceso a este fichero, almenos yo no lo encuentro en la carpeta de home/directorio ni en home/directorio/etc ni en public_html ni en ningún lugar tampoco tengo una carpeta llamada sbin o similar. Tampoco he podido encontrar php.ini que lo estuve buscando hace un rato

Comment: Ese fichero no está en ninguna de esas carpetas. ¿En qué sistema operativo está el servidor? ¿Tienes acceso de administrador en esa máquina o es un hosting compartido?

Comment: @A.Cedano Es un hosting compartido, acabo de mirar que es linux

Comment: Por lo general en hosting compartido no tienes acceso a `httpd.conf`, entonces debes hacer la configuración desde el archivo `.htaccess` que se encuentra en `public_html`. ¿Podrías mostrar lo que tienes en ese archivo `.htaccess` enmascarando posible información sensible?

Comment: Otra cosa, ¿cómo se llama el archivo donde encontraste el fallo *`AH01276: Cannot serve directory /home/directorio/public_html/php/ ...`*?

Comment: @A.Cedano ya está puesto en la pregunta el .htcacces, este fallo fue encontrado por el servicio tecnico del hosting después de preguntar por posibles fallos en los logs para determinar porque pasaba el primer error que comentaba, me dijeron que habia un error de spam de modsecurity que imagino que nada tendrá que ver y este error unicamente.

Comment: Ok, entonces ese error que refieres no lo encontraste en el log de errores de PHP. Antes que nada convendría ver qué errores están ocurriendo a nivel de PHP. Debes tener, o bien en la carpeta donde está el script PHP que falla un archivo llamado `error_log`, o bien un archivo global, fuera de `public_html`, en una carpeta llamada `logs`
, donde deberían estar los errores de PHP. Debes revisar qué errores están ocurriendo a nivel de PHP. Si tienes dificultad por ahora para encontrar dónde está el log de errores de PHP, puedes poner estas tres líneas al inicio del script `.php` problemático:

Comment: `ini_set('display_errors', '1');
 ini_set('display_startup_errors', '1');
 error_reporting(E_ALL);` Una vez puesto esto, guarda el archivo e intenta mandar un email. Esto es para que te muestre los posibles errores específicos de PHP, antes de seguir explorando posibles fallos en la configuración misma del servidor. Si hay fallos, deberías verlos en pantalla.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146839/discussion-between-mynameisunknown-and-a-cedano).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El error *`Language string failed to load: connect_host`* puede ocurrir por un problema al autenticarse usando el método `IsSMTP()`.

Si tal es el caso, prueba a cambiar esto:

```
$mail->IsSMTP();
```

Por esto:

```
$mail->Mailer = "mail";
```

En otros casos, este error ocurre porque PHPMailer no encuentra el archivo del idioma para mostrar ciertos mensajes.

Si tal es el caso, prueba a agregar:

```
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->SetLanguage("en", 'includes/phpMailer/language/');
```

O bien:

```
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->SetLanguage("es", 'includes/phpMailer/language/');
```

Fuente: [*Language string failed to load: from_failed[from_email_address]*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9109261/5587982)

Comment: Muchísimas gracias! ese era el error, ya no sabía si era por parte del servidor o que podía estar ocurriendo. Funcionando perfectamente!